# Bar Graph Style issue

Tags: r, graph

I am trying to create a bar chart.

This is my code:

```
ggplot(Bilat2GEO2,aes(x= region_par,y=total_exports))+
  geom_col()
```

and this is my graph

[image].

So I want to improve the style since it does not look nice. I want also to make the region's names separated from each other.

Comment: So what *exactly* is your question? Wanting to "improve the style" is quite vague and invites opinion-based answers. Better to ask specific questions. For example, to rotate the x-axis labels you can use `theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1))`. You can find *a lot* of freely available tutorials that discuss how to tweak `ggplot`s. I suggest spending a bit of time on research and then improving your post by asking a more *specific* question.

Comment: I want also to color the bar charts. Your answer was exact what I needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the region names readable, use `coord_flip()` function to turn the chart on it's side. To make chart look nicer, add color with the `fill=`.

```
ggplot(iris,aes(x=Species,y=Sepal.Length, fill=Species))+
  geom_col()+
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer but look when I use the fill function it does not change the color. ggplot(Bilat2GEO2,aes(x= region_par,y=total_imports),fill=region_par)+
  geom_col()+coord_flip()

Comment: Move `fill` inside the `aes(...)` code section

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer that uses the Iris data set, but is will reorder the columns as i'm sur thats what want to do to clean that chart up

```
iris %>%
  mutate(Species = fct_reorder(Species,  -Sepal.Length)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Species, Sepal.Length, group = Species, fill = Species)) +
  geom_col()+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("steelblue1", "grey5", "mediumpurple1"))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 70, vjust = 1, hjust=1))+
  xlab("")+
  ylab("")+
  ggtitle("Sepal Length",
          subtitle = "by Species")
```